# Mockito mocking method with class parameter vs actual object parameter

Tags: testing, mocking, mockito

What is the difference between these two as per Mockito -

> Mockito.when(serviceObject.myMethod(Customer.class)).thenThrow(new
>   RuntimeException());

and

> Customer customer = new Customer();
>   Mockito.when(serviceObject.myMethod(customer)).thenThrow(new
>   RuntimeException());

And if both serve the same purpose then using which one is considered to be best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding on your side - that method specification `myMethod(SomeClass.class)` is only **possible** when the signature of that method allows for a **class** parameter. Like:

```
Whatever myMethod(Object o) {
```

or directly

```
Whatever myMethod(Class<X> clazz) {
```

In other words: it is **not** Mockito that does something *special* about a parameter that happens to be of class Class!

Thus your first option is not something that works "in general". Example: I put down this code in a unit test:

```
static class Inner {
    public int foo(String s) { return 5; }
}

@Test
public void testInner() {
    Inner mocked = mock(Inner.class);
    when(mocked.foo(Object.class)).thenReturn(4);
    System.out.println(mocked.foo(""));
}
```

And guess what - the above does **not** compile. Because `foo()` doesn't allow for a **Class** parameter. We can rewrite to

```
static class Inner {
    public int foo(Object o) { return 5; }
}

@Test
public void testInner() {
    Inner mocked = mock(Inner.class);
    when(mocked.foo(Object.class)).thenReturn(4);
    System.out.println(mocked.foo(""));
}
```

And **now** the above compiles - but prints 0 (zero) when invoked. Because the above would be the same as `mocked.foo(eq(Object.class))`. In other words: when your method signature allows for passing a Class instance and you then *pass* a class instance, that is a simple mocking specification for mockito. In my example: when the incoming object would be `Object.class` - then 4 would be returned. But the incoming object is "" - therefore the Mockito default kicks in and 0 is returned.

I am with the other answer here - I think you are **mixing** up that older versions of Mockito asked you to write down `when(mocked.foo(any(ExpectedClass.class)))` - which can nowadays be written as `when(mocked.foo(any()))`. But `when(mocked.foo(ExpectedClass.class))` is **not** a Mockito construct - it is a simple method specification that gives a **specific** object to "match on" - and that specific object happens to be an instance of class Class.

Comment: I think I got it. In my case, I have defined `myMethod` method whose parameter type is Object. So, when I am doing `serviceObject.myMethod(Customer.class)` or `serviceObject.myMethod(CustomerDetail.class)`, Mockito is not acknowledging it. So, in this case, to make Mockito acknowledge it I have to  do `serviceObject.myMethod(any())`.
Just one more question, how will Mockito behave for `serviceObject.myMethod(any(Customer.class))` in this situation? Because I observe Mockito acknowledging this one also. Btw thanks a lot for this elaborate explanation, means a lot!!

Comment: Are you really **passing** class objects to your code? As said: what you have in your comment are specs that expect either a Custom or CustomerDetails class object.

Comment: No, the parameter type of the method is Object, but what I am passing is Customer and CustomerDetail.

Comment: A *customer* object or really Customer.class? And have you seen my updates?

Comment: Oh!!! Ya I am passing Customer.class. I somehow missed that update now I got it, thanks.

Comment: Sure - feel free to accept my answer(s) then at some point ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First one which uses generic `Customer` class to match type can also be written as:

> Mockito.when(serviceObject.myMethod(Mockito.any(Customer.class))).thenThrow(new
>   RuntimeException());

In case of the second one, you are passing the actual object that will be used in stubbing.

**Usage:**

If your method `myMethod` throws the exception based on the state of the `Customer` object then you can use the latter approach, where you can set the state of the Customer object appropriately.

However If your method `myMethod` does not depend on the `Customer` object to throw the exception rather you need it only to pass it as an argument just to invoke the method, then you can take the former approach.

Comment: Can you tell me what purpose `Mockito.any(Customer.class)` is serving and how is it different from `Mockito.any()`? Because what I thought the difference was, turns out it is not what it is. I thought doing `Mockito.any(Customer.class)` would mean any instance of Customer.class, but it is not what it seems like.

Comment: To understanding what I am trying to explain in my above comment please check this question -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149263/mockito-calling-same-method-with-different-class-paramter

Here you can see that Mockito is unable to differentiate between `Mockito.any(Customer.class)` and `Mockito.any(CustomerDetail.class)`. Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: To answer your question related to usage, `myMethod` is using the instance of the `Customer` which is getting instantiated inside the Method which I want to test. So although it is based on the state of the Customer I can't do anything about it. Even if I create the same Customer instance in the test, it won't work because the reference of that will be different from the reference of the Customer instance which is created inside the testing method.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, so there goes my upvote. But I then think that the OP has simply a misconception about what he is doing there. Thus I wrote my own other to clarify that aspect ;-)